# How to check if there is a match between reference string list and target string?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a reference string list converted from the dataframe.

Reference string list

```
brand_list = ['scurfa', 'seagull', 'seagull', 'seiko']
```

Sample input 1 for description_list

```
VINTAGE KING SEIKO 44-9990 Gold Medallion,Manual Winding with mod caseback.Serviced 2019.
```

Sample input 2 for description_list

```
Power reserve function at 12; push-pull crown at 4
Seiko NE57 auto movement with power reserve
Multilayered dial with SuperLuminova BG-W9
```

Desired output

```
SEIKO 44-9990 #extract together with model name
Seiko NE57 #extract together with model name
```

This is my sample code but the output it's not what I want

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 
import numpy as np

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

def clean(doc):
    no_punct = ""
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(doc.lower()) 
    filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words] 

    for w in word_tokens: 
        if w not in stop_words: 
            filtered_sentence.append(w) 

    return filtered_sentence

description_list = clean(soup_content.find('blockquote', { "class": "postcontent restore" }).text)

if pandas.Series(np.array(description_list)).isin(np.array(brand_list)).any() == True:
    brand_result = [i for i in description_list if i in brand_list] 
    print(brand_result[0])

    if pandas.Series(np.array(description_list)).isin(np.array(model_list)).any() == True:
        model_result = [i for i in description_list if i in model_list] 
        print(model_result[0])
    else:
        print('Unknown')
else:
    print('Unknown')
    print('Unknown')
```

Comment: why use nltk for this, just use regex am i missing something?

Comment: @Datanovice I don't think regex can solve this problem.

Comment: I think a regex is the solution. How do the "model names" look like usually?

Comment: @Arnaud its similar to brand_list. its a quite long list, around 3k. same goes to brand_list, 3k.

Comment: See https://pythex.org/?regex=seiko%20(%5B%5E%5Cs%5D%2B)&test_string=VINTAGE%20KING%20SEIKO%2044-9990%20Gold%20Medallion%2CManual%20Winding%20with%20mod%20caseback.Serviced%202019.%0APower%20reserve%20function%20at%2012%3B%20push-pull%20crown%20at%204%0ASeiko%20NE57%20auto%20movement%20with%20power%20reserve%0AMultilayered%20dial%20with%20SuperLuminova%20BG-W9&ignorecase=1&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0

Comment: So you know exactly how model names look like from the beginning?

Comment: yes, @Arnaud. if you look closely, if I successfully extracted the brand name, automatically I can extract the model name.

Comment: then how about the find the match string using regex? I saw the pattern but the implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go for a regular expression.

```
brand_list = ['scurfa', 'seagull', 'seagull', 'seiko']
regular_expression = rf"({'|'.join(brand_list)}) ([^\s]+)"
```

Some words about this regular expression:

- we use the string constructor `rf""` which means you want this string to be both `raw` (required by the `re` module) and `formattable` (to include variables using brackets `{}`)
- `'|'.join(brand_list)` enables to get something like `(scurfa|seagull)` to match any of the required brands in `brand_list`
- adding `([^\s]+)` enables to catch the word right after the brand (assumed to be the model name)

Finally:

```
import re

description = """
VINTAGE KING SEIKO 44-9990 Gold Medallion,Manual Winding with mod caseback.Serviced 2019.
Power reserve function at 12; push-pull crown at 4
Seiko NE57 auto movement with power reserve
Multilayered dial with SuperLuminova BG-W9
Testing for a ScURFA 42342
"""

print([" ".join(t) for t in re.findall(regular_expression, description, re.IGNORECASE)])
```

Which gives:

```
['SEIKO 44-9990', 'Seiko NE57', 'ScURFA 42342']
```

Comment: let me try it first

Comment: Yes @Datanovice, just added some explanations. Tell me if that helps.

Comment: @Arnaud what if I want to replace ([^\s]+) with model_list? the model_list similar like this ['44-9990 Gold Medallion', 'NE57 auto', '42342 ']

Comment: Supposing you have a `model_list`, you could imagine having this regular expression now: `regular_expression = rf"({'|'.join(brand_list)}) ({'|'.join(model_list)})"`. See https://pythex.org/?regex=(scurfa%7Cseagul%7Cseiko)%20(44-9990%20Gold%20Medallion%7CNE57%20auto%7C42342)&test_string=VINTAGE%20KING%20SEIKO%2044-9990%20Gold%20Medallion%2CManual%20Winding%20with%20mod%20caseback.Serviced%202019.%0APower%20reserve%20function%20at%2012%3B%20push-pull%20crown%20at%204%0ASeiko%20NE57%20auto%20movement%20with%20power%20reserve%0AMultilayered%20dial%20with%20SuperLuminova%20BG-W9&ignorecase=1